# Calculating h-index

Tags: c, algorithm, list, tree, sorting

I need to calculate the [h-index](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/H-index) from a list of publications i stored in a tree.

What i did is traversing the tree in decrescent order obtaining a list of position-number of citations

it looks like:

```
line 1 10
line 2 5
line 3 4
line 4 0
```

I should stop at line 3 and return 3. The problem is with the examples given and in this case

```
line 1 4
line 2 0
line 3 0
```

it stops at 2 because 4>1 but 0>3 is false. It should return 1 instead. Can you explain me why? I know it's more like a mathematician question, but after that i could need to re-implement it if something is deeply wrong.

Here is the code

```
  int index_h_calc(rbtree_node n, int *i){
    if (n == NULL) {
        fputs("<empty tree>\n", stdout);
        return 0;
    }
    if (n->right != NULL)
      index_h_calc(n->right,i);


    graduat *grad;
    grad=n->value;

    if(DEBUG)
      printf("linea %d %d %s\n ",*i,(int)grad->tot,grad->name);

    if(*i+1>=(int)grad->tot) {
      return *i;
    } else
      *i+=1;

    if (n->left != NULL)
      index_h_calc(n->left,i);

    return *i;
  }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This has several solutions on [github](https://github.com/pjotrp/bioruby-bioinformatics-impact), eg in Ruby, equivalent to your `n` is `citePages` and being the `h-index` calculated

```
function h_index(){
        var hArray = new Array();
        var x = 0;
        for(var i = 0; i < citePages.length; i++){
            var citeArray = citePages[i];           
            for(var j = 0; j < citeArray.length; j++){
                // The multiplication by one is a hack to convert the string type into a numerical type
                hArray[x++] = citeArray[j]*1;
            }
        }
        hArray.sort(sortNumber);
        //alert(hArray);
        for(var i = 0; i < hArray.length; i++){
            if(i > hArray[i]){
                return hArray[i-1];
            }
        }
    }
```

previous function -

```
function getCitationCount(responseText){
  if (responseText == null){
    _gel("sContent").innerHTML = "<i>Invalid data.</i>";
            alert("There is no data.");
        return;
        }

 var cite_exists = 1;
 var cite_str_len = 14;
 var len_of_Cite_by_str = 9;
 var citeArray = new Array();
 for(var i = 0; cite_exists > 0; i++) 
  {
    cite_exists = responseText.search('Cited by');
    if(cite_exists == -1){
        //alert("No more citations for given Author!");
        //return;
    }else{
        var tmp_string = responseText.substr(cite_exists, cite_str_len);
        var end = (tmp_string.indexOf("<")-len_of_Cite_by_str);
        citeArray[i] = tmp_string.substr(len_of_Cite_by_str, end);
        publications++;
        responseText = responseText.substr(cite_exists+cite_str_len, responseText.length);
    }
 }
return citeArray;
}
```

If this doesn't provide a solution then the problem to be verifiable - so we really need example data, eg a jsfiddle of typical data stating what result is expected in each case, given that this is a mathematical rather than coding question and can only be tested with a populated complex data structure.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps I am missing some subtlety, but isn't the answer just to subtract one from the line number? That is, if `i` is the line number and `n` is the number of citations, you traverse the tree until you find a line with `n < i` and then return the h-index as `i - 1`.

Comment: ...shouldn't that be, "then return the h-index as *n* - 1"?  Otherwise it sounds right to me...

Comment: @Dmitri: no, it has to be `i - 1`.  Consider the first example of the OT: we stop at line 4 (because `0 < 4`) and return an h-index of `4 - 1 = 3`.  In the second example, we stop at line 2 and return `1`.

Comment: Oops..  When I wrote that i had `n` and `i` backward in my mind for some reason.